# Can't download a directory and files therein using wget

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I want to download all files in some directory using wget. But I can't. It saids,

```
wget -r -np ftp://myID:password@server.com/.../Directory

Login (Server)... Connected.
Logging in as my ID... Log in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... Done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /../Directory ... Done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> LIST ... 
No such file or directory ‘.’.
```

What is the problem in this commands?
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most modern FTP servers, as modern as the FTP gets, that means you do not have sufficient permissions to access the directory and/or its content.

Also note, that many FTP servers by default allow anonymous access, but forbid access to the local users (to prevent sending passwords as plain text). Unfortunate quirk of that *feature* is that under some circumstances a local user can manage to log-in, but not as the local user, but as an anonymous one. And as an anonymous user might have insufficient permissions.

All in all, it is very likely that the problem is on the side of the FTP server, and not wget's (client's) problem.